# Custom link uses hard-coded ids

Tags: custom-button, dynamic

I am working on a client org, and it uses hard-coded ids in a **custom button/link** which are pointing to Account (sobject) fields. This particular detail page button is going to create "New Contact" with pre-defined information as one could see from below URL, used as the button-URL.

> https://abc.salesforce.com/003/e?retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}&accid={!Account.Id}&con6={!Account.Department__c}&00N60000001KB3g={!Account.Billing_Address_Street__c}&00N60000001KB3l={!Account.Billing_Address_City__c}&00N60000001KB3v={!Account.Billing_Address_Country__c}&00N60000001KB3q={!Account.Billing_Address_State__c}&00N60000001KB3d={!Account.Billing_Address_Postal_Zipcode__c}&00N60000001K8yX={!Account.Billing_Address_Street__c}&00N60000001K8yU={!Account.Billing_Address_City__c}&00N60000001K8yV={!Account.Billing_Address_Country__c}&00N60000001K8yT={!Account.Billing_Address_State__c}&00N60000001K8yS={!Account.Billing_Address_Postal_Zipcode__c}&00N60000001gXHY={!Account.Billing_Address_County__c}

Can I replace those hard-coded ids with fields retrieved dynamically?

Comment: Do those ids match an actual record in Salesforce? I don't think those are record id's they look more like the field ids that are generated on the page

Comment: Indeed, they are account field Ids.

Comment: Yes but its not as easy as it should be - see e.g. [Querying Custom Object and Field IDs via Tooling API](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/01/05/querying-custom-object-and-field-ids-via-tooling-api/)

Comment: @KeithC: I have already seen that but I want that sort-of-functionality in custom button/link. :-)

Comment: You can reference hierarchical custom settings via $Setup in a custom button or link. So create a custom setting to hold each field ID and either set them manually there or write code to populate the custom setting automatically.

Comment: I really like the sound of that. I will give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a custom hierarchical setting, and added all the required fields and then used "manage" to assign values to the fields. After setting up my custom-setting, accessed their fields as shown below:

```
{!$Setup.CustomSettingName__c.CustomFieldName__c}
```

References:

1. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_accessing.htm&language=en_US
2. http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/08/using-hierarchy-custom-settings-in-salesforce-com/
3. Keith C. comments